# How to prompt the user for credentials when connecting to VSO using API? via VssAadCredential

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm creating a custom application to connect to Visual Studio online, backed by WAAD - I'm using the NuGet packages (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet)

- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient

Here is my code...(passing in username and password works but I want to be prompted)

```
        VssAadCredential aadcred = new VssAadCredential();
        VssCredentials cred = new VssCredentials(aadcred);
        cred.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;

        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient buildClient =
            new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient(new Uri("https://myproject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/"), cred);

        var result = buildClient.GetBuildsAsync("My Project");

        foreach (var item in result.Result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Definition.Name);
        }
```

I would like the Windows Azure Active Directory prompt to appear like this if the user is not authenticated...

[image]

How can I accomplish this? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the VssAadCredential class doesn't support interactive flow to prompt to provide user name and password. You have to passing username and password.

Here is what I get when check the VssAadCredential class in Object Browser (quoted it for your reference):

*Summary:
Currently it is impossible to get whether prompting is allowed from the credential itself without reproducing the logic used by VssClientCredentials. Since this is a stop gap solution to get Windows integrated authentication to work against AAD via ADFS for now this class will only support that one, non-interactive flow. We need to assess how much we want to invest in this legacy stack rather than recommending people move to the VssConnect API for future authentication needs.*

Comment: Ok thanks for the post - I guess I should therefore be investigating the VssConnect API - do you have an example how to do this connecting to Visual Studio Online?